# Symfony 2: Deploy assets from non bundles

Tags: symfony, assetic

I wonder if there's a possibility to deploy assets from a custom folder.

I've separated my business logic and entities from the bundles and now I would like to have a centralized place to my custom js library.

Is there any configuration available for symfony or assetic to deploy a custom folder that doesn't belong to a bundle? TIA

Comment: Bower with a custom .bowerrc file installing assets in web/componets maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found an answer without intention LOL.

Looking a repo on github I saw that Assetic can be configured to receive some input resources and generate a unique output like this:

```
assetic:
    debug:  %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: true
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        yui_css:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/nervo/yuicompressor/yuicompressor.jar
        yui_js:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/nervo/yuicompressor/yuicompressor.jar
        less:
            node: /usr/bin/node
            node_paths: [/usr/local/bin/]
            apply_to: "\.less$"
    assets:
        scripts:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../src/MyResources/script.js
                - @FoundationViewBundle/Resources/public/js/*
            filters:
                - cssrewrite
                - yui_js
            output: js/scripts.min.js
            debug: %kernel.debug%
        stylesheets:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../src/MyResources/stylesheet.css
                - @FoundationViewBundle/Resources/public/css/*
            filters:
                - less
                - yui_css
            output: css/style.min.css
            debug: %kernel.debug%
```

Which can be used directly with:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/style.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="{{ asset('js/scripts.min.js') }}"></script>
```

or using Assetic aliases:

```
{% stylesheets '@stylesheets' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}

{% javascripts '@scripts' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```